# How to use simple operator on this?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm create some sample code and still begineer
    class Number

```
def initialize(name)
    @first = []
    @second = []
    @final = 0

end

def input
    print "Please input first number"
    @first = gets.chomp
    print "Please input second number"
    @second = gets.chomp

end

def output
    @final = @first * @second
    puts @final

end



end

number = Number.new('Jakz')
number.class
number.input
number.output
```

I want to sum the 2 input number but its give error because the 2 number become a string not a number.How to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at [`String#to_i`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-to_i).  While you're there, take some time to learn about many other useful methods that String provides.

Comment: What does this have to do with Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets` returns a String. The prompt does not know that you are requesting a number. Calling [`to_f`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f) does its best to convert the string to a floating point number

```
def input
    print "Please input first number"
    @first = gets.chomp.to_f
    print "Please input second number"
    @second = gets.chomp.to_f

end
```

be aware that if the user enters something that is not a number - the above code does not validate it, and will most probably set the variables to `0`.

Comment: When I insert 3.3 ,it become 3. When I insert float number it will become integer. How to deal with it?

Comment: Use `to_f`, not `to_i` for floats

Comment: It's worth noting that unlike Perl, PHP, and JavaScript, Ruby does not automatically cast from strings to numbers. You must explicitly request this with things like `to_i` or `to_f`.

Comment: @JakzAizzat - I've updated the answer to fit floating point numbers.